# Jenkins poll vs webhook

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I am new to Jenkins, was curious to know how does the Jenkins poll feature works and how does it utlize system resources.

What could be best practice to use in CI system - Jenkins poll or github webhook and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [very easy answer, answered by Kohsuke](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/), the creator of jenkins himself. Polling is less efficient, both for your computers, and for your people, since you have to wait--on the order of minutes--for your builds to happen, instead of them happening essentially instantly. We used to use polling before we switched to jenkins, and the biggest thing that people talk about is that "holy crap, jenkins builds fast." It's not jenkins, it's webhook pushing to trigger builds. Do that.

Comment: Agreed..!! searched some blogs, all of them lands on the same conclusion that webhook is better anytime.

Comment: Webhooks are best used when connecting a PAAS-git repo provider like gitlab and a PAAS-CI provider like travisci. This is where webhooks makes sense. A git hook plugin is entirely different than a feature of github or gitlab called webhooks. Webhooks are a specific configuration of a PAAS-hosted git repository like github or gitlab. They can’t be stored as code. Jenkins is a task runner. Polling may be inefficient but it’s minimal compared to design patterns you’ll be forced in to using using PAAS-git repository providers and Jenkins.

Comment: The article does not mention webhooks and does not answer the posters question. The author of the article is promoting a git module that supports a post receive and post commit function.

Comment: What about missed webhooks, if your scm (e.g. bitbucket) is self-managed and some networking/power outages occur, how should you approach it?
Does polling store the last built code version? if it catches 2 commits at once?